# increasing number of partitions in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I was using Hive for executing SQL queries on a project. I used ORC with 50k Stride for my data and have created the hive ORC tables using this configuration with a certain date column as partition.

Now I wanted to use Spark SQL to benchmark the same queries operating on the same data.

I executed the following query

```
val q1 = sqlContext.sql("select col1,col2,col3,sum(col4),sum(col5) from mytable where date_key=somedatkye group by col1,col2,col3")
```

In hive it takes 90 seconds for this query. But spark takes 21 minutes for the same query and on looking at the job, i found the issue was because Spark creates 2 stages and on the first stage, it has only 7 tasks, one each for each of the 7 blocks of data within that given partition in orc file. The blocks are of different size, one is 5MB while the other is 45MB and because of this stragglers take more time leading to taking too much time for the job.

How do i mitigate this issue in spark. How do i manually increase the number of partitions, resulting in increasing the number of tasks in stage 1, even though there are only 7 physical blocks for the given range of the query.

Comment: I strongly believe that the difference is not in the data skew, but in the fact that Hive uses **predicate push-down** to skip-scan all ORC stripes that do not match your WHERE clause. See how you can activate it in Spark in http://fr.hortonworks.com/blog/bringing-orc-support-into-apache-spark/ (caveat: it took several JIRAs to have it work properly, check that your Spark version is safe)

Comment: Disclaimer: if your WHERE clause applies to the *partition key* then predicate push-down will not help. After re-reading your question I'm not really sure.

Comment: My where clause applies to the partition key so I don't think predicate push down is the issue here. I physically verified this by looking at the hive warehouse in the file system and under the date_key i am looking for, there are exactly 7 files and spark creates exactly 7 partitions with the input size equal to that of the file size. Hope this clears it up.

Comment: Hive should *also* start 7 mappers, by definition. Or even less, since your files are really, really small and could apply for *CombineInputFormat*. Even the lack of vectorization (SPARK-16060) cannot explain why Spark is so slow.